# How to fire events in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to execute button click event in MVC4. I am new for MVC4 and don't know where to write event, function and how to handle them b/w Model,View and Control.

is there any one have idea about same?

I will be grateful, if some one help me with detail explanation and example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Answer (score 4):

MVC 4 is essentially stateless, so unlike Web Forms, there's no "automatic" way to wire a button click on the browser UI to your C# code.

The way it's handled generally is that when you click on a button (e.g. `<button>` maybe?), it fires off an HTTP request either via AJAX or standard browser redirect. That HTTP request gets handled by an action on your controller.

So say you've got this controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public string Foo() {
        return "Bar!";
    }
}
```

You can wire up your markup and jQuery like so in Razor:

```
<button id="my-button">Call Foo!</button>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#my-button').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url : '@Url.Action("Foo", "MyController")',
                type : 'GET'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's basically it in a very quick gist.

Comment: I tried same but I think script is not running. I am using master page in my project. Does this require additional things?

Comment: Well, the code I posted uses jQuery, so you need that at least. Other than that, there shouldn't be anything else.

And by "master page", I'm assuming you mean a layout.

Comment: Now, I am able to run scrip after replacing <asp:Button> with <button> but ajax portion not working.I am not getting debug point at public string Foo() and also not getting alert message in success: function (result) {alert(result)}

Answer (score 3):

I would start with the basics. You don't need jquery... Have a read of http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx to understand how asp.net MVC works.

Define two methods inside your controller with the same name. The method defined with HttpVerbs.Post will be the method called when you click the button (a POST request).

Put a form around your button pointing to your method and when you click the button it will run the method named with the HttpVerbs.Post.

**View**

```
<form action="Home/MyMethod" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <button text="Click me" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string username)
    {
        // notice the string username matches the <input id="username"...
        // alternatively you can pass a FormCollection to this method.
        return View();
    }
}
```